# Do we have to lower our gaze towards female characters in books, animation, etc.?

Tags: practical-islam, women, image

Do we have to lower our gaze towards towards female characters in animations, games and books? Or just in real life?

Comment: I think morally yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that whatever sight, situation and action that risk you falling into sin must be avoided. And sin includes lustful glances or looks at women whether in person, drawn or filmed.